OBD2 scanner for Ford Ranger 4.0 95
I have a 95 4.0 Ranger STX that I just replaced the head gaskets. After a couple of days of driving it afterwards, the dreaded "check engine" light came up. I have de OBD2 port under the steering wheel column, so I believe I could use an OBD2 scanner to check the error. I got a cheap ELM327 Bluetooth scanner that doesn't connect to the ECU. What is the recommended pair of scanner and Android app that would work? The cheapest the better. Thanks!

I got a OBD2 raster and it worked. Got the classic P0401, fixed the EGR intake hose, reset the code and now everything is fine. So a Ranger 95 STX after manufactured after June is indeed OBD2, but maybe not all scanners can read it.

If I'm not mistaken, your '95 Ford Ranger is OBDI, not OBDII. Aftermarket code readers didn't exist for diyers. The diy code reader uses a paper clip to short terminals A and B, turn on ignition and observe one of the indicator lights flashing, counting up with a pause between flashes. . Here's one link; https://www.troublecodes.net/ford/

I managed to use a OBD2 reader that reads more codes and it worked. After researching, Rangers manufactured after June 95 are OBD2, while previous ones are indeed OBD1.
